# Is the semantic component of a generative grammar especially difficult to incorporate in psycholinguistic proccessing models?

Tags: syntax, semantics, psycholinguistics

It is often said that it is difficult to match up the structure rules of a grammar with psychologically realistic models of competence.  I was wondering if the semantic component was especially problematic (even over and above the challenges relating to the syntax in this regard).

Comment: Can you add some quotes of people who have said that it is difficult, so that we can get a better idea of what the difficulties are?

Comment: It's basically a difference between the way linguists model and the way psychologists model. They come from very different positions, epistemologically; it's no wonder they don't recognize the others' ontologies.

Answer (score 1):

You're asking two different questions between the title and the description.

1. **Is generative grammar difficult to incorporate into cognitive processing models?**
   Not particularly. In fact, because generative grammar constraints what is meant by language. This makes it much easier to design experiments within the paradigm. However, you have to remember that, as originally formulated, generative grammar does not make any predictions about the online processing of language. It is exclusively concerned with 'competence' rather than 'performance'. But it is easily laid out into experimentally isolatable components, and a lot of psycholinguists have chosen to adopt its general approach as a sort of 'basic linguistic theory'. Unfortunately, this has led to a significant impoverishment of psycholinguistic research in the last forty years or so.
2. **Is the semantic component of generative grammar difficult to reconcile with psycholinguistic models?** This makes the assumption that there is such as thing as a coherent semantic theory of generative grammar seeking cognitive plausibility. All the theories I've looked at are based on some version of formal logic. This is not too difficult to model experimentally but if you look at actual psycholinguistic research, nobody looks at this much (beyond some work in inference and presupposition). That's because natural language semantics is much more difficult to map onto generative linguistics than natural language syntax. So in practice, most psycholinguists rely on a sort of folk theory of meaning informed by various models.

But the question that would be more interesting to ask is: **Do we have enough experimental psycholinguistic evidence to support a comprehensive processing model of natural language semantics and pragmatics?**

The answer to that is definitely NOT because of point 1. We need a far richer experimental paradigm within psycholinguistics that is not confined to the lab (I find Discursive Psychology very inspiring in this respect). We need psycholinguists to look at the broader semantic research (and not just the scraps off the table of working syntacticians). We need to jettison primitive concepts based on the dictionary model of meaning and look at semantics as a process that happens both consciously and unconsciously, individually and collectively, cognitively and affectively. We need to once and for all bury the semantics/pragmatics distinction. We need a non-storage model of memory and recall. Far more research on framing and cross-linguistic research in non-WEIRD contexts.

Some of these things exist in germinal form but we're far from a model of how meaning is processed that could serve as general hermeneutic underpinning for the interpretation of a broad range of phenomena.

Comment: This is very informative, thank you.  Re point 2, it has been suggested that one problem is the common assumption that the semantic component is some form of Montague Grammar, which emphasizes possible-worlds truth conditions.  These don't necessarily tell you much about how language users understand sentences.

Comment: I agree @John. Only I'd go even further and say that's it utterly preposterous to think that truth conditional semantics can represent anything but a fraction of how people construct meaning. Every time I look at history of linguistics and philosophy of language I am staggered how long this has stuck with us and how many people still try to rescue this. (That's not to put down the very useful branches of logic that this line of reasoning has spawned, they're just only pale shadows of the complexity we need for real semantics.)

Comment: Agreed. It's a game for philosophers and logicians, but has remarkably little to do with actual talk. The only excuse for formalization is either because it makes it possible to prove theorems, or because it makes it possible to produce machine-washable semantics. But neither of these are true of formal semantics -- there are no theorems nor proofs, and nobody uses it in CL/NLP. I agree that _preposterous_ is the proper term for the situation; however, there's enough  preposterousness to go around.